# Associating children via parents in parallel inheritence hierarchies

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-factory

I need to develop a C++ solution to represent an object with features, where the objects and features are represented by different objects, but the actual implementation of the association is implemented in a derived class which exists to encapsulate an external implementation.  I know that this kind of thing is typical of inheritance-related problems, so I want opinions on the correct solution.  The implementation part should be seen as a sort of API boundary -- the user code should not see it, or see it only once in order to select the implementation.

Here's an example:

```
#include <cstdio>

// External implementation 1
class SomeShape {};
class SomeBody { public: SomeShape *shape; };

// External implementation 2
class OtherShape {};
class OtherBody { public: OtherShape *shape; };

//////////////

class Shape
{
public:
  virtual const char *name() { return "Shape"; }
};

class Body
{
public:
  virtual void setShape(Shape *s) = 0;
};

class Factory
{
public:
  virtual Shape *makeShape() = 0;
  virtual Body *makeBody() = 0;
};

//////////////

class AShape : public Shape
{
public:
  SomeShape *someShape;
  virtual const char *name() { return "AShape"; }
};

class ABody : public Body
{
protected:
  SomeBody *someBody;
  AShape *shape;
public:
  ABody() { someBody = new SomeBody; }
  virtual void setShape(Shape *s)
  {
    shape = static_cast<AShape*>(s);
    printf("Setting shape: %s\n", s->name());
    someBody->shape = shape->someShape;
  }
};

class AFactory : public Factory
{
public:
  virtual Shape *makeShape()
    { return new AShape(); }
  virtual Body *makeBody()
    { return new ABody(); }
};

//////////////

class BShape : public Shape
{
public:
  OtherShape *otherShape;
  virtual const char *name() { return "BShape"; }
};

class BBody : public Body
{
protected:
  OtherBody *otherBody;
  BShape *shape;
public:
  BBody() { otherBody = new OtherBody; }
  virtual void setShape(Shape *s)
  {
    shape = static_cast<BShape*>(s);
    printf("Setting shape: %s\n", s->name());
    otherBody->shape = shape->otherShape;
  }
};

class BFactory : public Factory
{
public:
  virtual Shape *makeShape()
    { return new BShape(); }
  virtual Body *makeBody()
    { return new BBody(); }
};
```

Thus, the role of the above is to allow the user to instantiate `Body` and `Shape` objects, which exist to manage associating underlying implementations `SomeShape`/`SomeBody` or `OtherShape`/`OtherBody`.

Then, a main function exercising both implementations could be,

```
int main()
{
  // Of course in a real program we would return
  // a particular Factory from some selection function,
  // this should ideally be the only place the user is
  // exposed to the implementation selection.
  AFactory f1;
  BFactory f2;

  // Associate a shape and body in implementation 1
  Shape *s1 = f1.makeShape();
  Body *b1 = f1.makeBody();
  b1->setShape(s1);

  // Associate a shape and body in implementation 2
  Shape *s2 = f2.makeShape();
  Body *b2 = f2.makeBody();
  b2->setShape(s2);

  // This should not be possible, compiler error ideally
  b2->setShape(s1);

  return 0;
}
```

So, the parts that I am not happy about here are the `static_cast<>` calls in `setShape()`, because they build in an assumption that the correct object type has been passed in, without any compile-time type checking.  Meanwhile, `setShape()` can accept any `Shape`, when in reality only a derived class should be accepted here.

However, I don't see how compile-time type checking could be possible if I want the user code to operate on the `Body`/`Shape` level and not the `ABody`/`AShape` or `BBody`/`BShape` level.  However, switching the code so that `ABody::setShape()` accepts only an `AShape*` would make the whole factory pattern useless, for one thing, and would force the user code to be aware of which implementation is in use.

In addition it seems like the `A`/`B` classes are an extra level of abstraction over `Some`/`Other`, which exist only to support them at compile time, yet these are not intended to be exposed to the API, so what's the point... they serve only as a kind of impedance-matching layer, forcing both `SomeShape` and `OtherShape` into the `Shape` mold.

But what are my alternative choices?  Some run-time type checking could be used, such as `dynamic_cast<>` or an `enum`, but I'm looking for something a little more elegant, if possible.

How would you do this in another language?

Comment: I think that, based on what I understand you're saying, using the dynamic_cast<> is probably the simplest option for this. I don't think you'll be able to do any compile time type checks when using runtime polymorphism like you are.

Comment: I'm thinking one solution could be to move makeShape() from the Factory to the Body(), returning an object that is _already_ associated.. but the exact solution still escapes me.  Not sure how generalizable it is, either.  I'm asking the question because I feel like something clever can be done here... that programmer itch.. ;)  But maybe I'm off on the wrong foot.

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting thought. What if you modified the Factory to have a virtual method where it returns a body and shape pair? where the returned body is made to be associated with the returned shape?

Comment: Not bad, I'll play with the idea tomorrow.  I didn't mention that a given body might have several shapes, but it's a start..

Comment: I've hit on another idea here, which I think is more what I'm aiming for.  Instead of establishing a hierarchy where the implementation is represented as derived classes, I'm going to try having the structure of body->shape mappings be expressed using a very basic set of classes.  In a second pass, I'll traverse this structure and generate "backend" structures that correspond, mirroring the desired relationships using a particular implementation.  I'm just trying to figure out whether this will require back-pointers for efficiency when the structure is updated..

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis of your design issue**

Your solution implements the [abstract factory design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html), with:

- `AFactory` and `BFactory` are concrete factories of the abstract `Factory`
- `ABody` and `AShape` on one hand and `BBody` and `BShape` on the other hand are concrete products of abstract products `Body` and `Shape`.
- The Axxx classes form a familiy of related classes.  So do the Bxxx classes.

The issue you worry about is that an the method `Body::setShape()` depends on an abstract shape argument, whereas the concrete implementation expects in reality a concrete shape.

As you've rightly pointed out, the downcast to the concrete `Shape` suggests a potential design flaw. And it will not be possible to catch the errors at compile-time, because the whole pattern is designed to be dynamic and flexible at run time, and the virtual function can't be templatized.

**Alternative 1: make your current design a little bit safer**

Use the `dynamic_cast<>` to check at runtime if the downcast is valid.  Consequence:

- the ugly casting is very well isolated in a single function.
- the runtime check is only done when necessary, i.e. the only time you set the shape.

**Alternative 2: adopt a design with strong isolation**

A better design, would be to isolate the different products. So one product class would only use the abstract interface of the other classes of the same family and ignore their concrete specificity.

Consequences:

- very robust design enforcing superior separation of concerns
- you could factorize the `Shape*` member at the level of the abstract class, and perhaps even de-virtualize `setShape()`.
- but this comes at expense fo rigidity: you couldn't make use of family specific interface.  This could be very embarassing, if for example the goal is that the family represents a native UI, knowing that products are highly interdependent and need to use native API (that's the typical example in the book of the Gang of 4).

**Alternative 3: templatize dependent types**

Opt for a template based implementation of your abstract factory.  The general idea, is that you define the internal dependencies between products, using a template implementation.

So in your example Shape, `AShape` and `BShape` are unchanged as there is no dependency to other produts.  But Body depends on a Shape, ad you want to have `ABody` depending on `AShape`, whereas `BBody` should depend on `BShape`.

The trick is then to use a template instead of an abstract class:

```
template<class Shape>   
class Body 
{
  Shape *shape;     
public:
  void setShape(Shape *s) { 
    shape=s; 
    printf("Setting shape: %s\n", s->name());
  }
};
```

Then you would define `ABody` by deriving it from `Body<AShape>`:

```
class ABody : public Body<AShape>
{
protected:
  SomeBody *someBody;
public:
  ABody() { someBody = new SomeBody; }
};
```

This is all very nice, but how shall this work with the abstract factory ?  Well same principle:  templatize instead of virtualize.

```
template <class Shape, class Body>
class Factory
{
public:
  Shape *makeShape()
    { return new Shape(); }
  Body *makeBody()
    { return new Body(); }
};

// and now the concrete factories
using BFactory = Factory<BShape, BBody>; 
using AFactory = Factory<AShape, ABody>;
```

The consequence is that you have to know at compile time which concrete factory and concrete products you intend to use.  THis can be done using C++11 `auto` :

```
AFactory f1;        // as before

auto *s1 = f1.makeShape();    // type is deduced from the concrete factory
auto *b1 = f1.makeBody();
b1->setShape(s1);
```

With this approach you will no longuer be able to mixup products of different families.  The following statement will cause an error:

```
b2->setShape(s1);   // error: no way to convert an AShape* to a BShape*
```

And here an **[online demo](http://ideone.com/VfYZMq)**

Comment: In the end I've adopted a different strategy, I'm not sure if it fits into your answer, perhaps alternative 3?  Basically, I did away with the factories, and the user only deals with creating `Body` and `Shape` directly.  Then this whole thing is passed into basically an AShape/ABody creator function, which takes the Body/Shape objects and converts them into ABody/AShape objects, and operates on those.  Similarly for BBody/BShape.  Thus, the user never sees the implementation.